# Can't figure out what kind of web payload request

Tags: python, python-2.7, session, python-requests, shopify

I am writing a python script that automate payment.

So I am currently trying to figure out how this payment processor is sending it payload to external sites.

I monitored POST request with chrome and it sent POST with this following payload
(xxxx are my credit numbers, verification value, and expiration date

```
{"credit_card":{"number":"xxxx xxxx xxxx xxx","name":"ad adf","month":'xx',"year":'xxxx',"verification_value":"xxx"}}
```

At first I thought it was json, so I tried sending with following:

```
data = {"credit_card":{"number":"xxxx xxxx xxxx xxx","name":"ad adf","month":'xx',"year":'xxxx',"verification_value":"xxxx"}}

session.post(paymentURL, data=json.dumps(data), headers = cHeaders)
```

I got 200 response code but it seem like payment didn't go through.

Next, I tried

```
session.post(paymentURL, data=data, headers = cHeaders)
```

but same problem, payment not going through. Any idea what I am doing right?

Comment: try it without json.dumps(data), just send the dictionary data.

Comment: I did without json.dump. Same problem

Comment: post the url, maybe you miss some GET/POST call, or try to do it with Python+Selenium.

Comment: Ok so this is the url. The following payload request occur when submitting payment method. It sent a requests to external site elb.deposit.com(forgot url. Currently on phone) and it return an ID that we must use to finally submit order. I did series of get/post to reach to last step: payment method. I checked to make sure I am on last step. I then sent a post request to external and use the return id to send a final POST request . However payment not going thru or it not even throwing an error such as invalid security code, etc. URL in next comment

Comment: https://checkout.shopify.com/1671144/checkouts/e2ff66cebde37770d6fa2cc90e3c3b0d?checkout%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Baddress1%5D=&checkout%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Baddress2%5D=&checkout%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Bcity%5D=&checkout%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Bcompany%5D=&checkout%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Bcountry%5D=&checkout%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Bprovince%5D=&checkout%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Bzip%5D=&method=shipping&step=contact_information. Would appreciate if you can help. Been doing this for past few hours and can't figure it out

Comment: What is `data`, what is `cHeaders`, do you need to send `GET` request first to grab session `cookies` that should be used with `POST`? Provide with more related details